# filling area with elements using float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am working with DIVs with float:left

when DIV 2 increases size

we get something like this:

```
+---+ +----+
| 1 | |    |
+---+ |    |
      |  2 |
      |    |
      |    |
      +----+
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
```

Is there a way to achieve this:

```
+---+ +----+
| 1 | |    |
+---+ |    |
+---+ |  2 |
| 3 | |    |
+---+ |    |
      +----+
```

Without having to resort to jquery?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle testcase?

Comment: judging form your comment on the first answer I dont think you'll get a css only answer. look into jquery masonry, will make your life a lot easier imo. made another fiddle solution that you could use if you want to wrap the divs. http://jsfiddle.net/RsYgR/

Comment: jquery masonry looks like the best solution :)

Comment: but is it possible to change the height of an element after it has been placed?

Comment: i think you cant.. so close..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS3 **:nth-child** property for this. Write like this:

```
.innerdiv:nth-child(even){
    float:right;
    border-color:red;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RsYgR/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="left" style="float: left;">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
    .......
    <div class="boxN"></div>
</div>
<div class="right" style="float: right;"></div>
```

This will work for any number of boxes, it's like having two columns left that will stretch on height and right that will stretch too.

Here is the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/SVbyj/

Comment: that is complicated because the number of boxes is variable and al of them can increase in height

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point here, do you want to keep both sides same height?

Answer (score 1):

So this is the best solution I came up with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {  //json array with box info
    createHTML.box(i);  //creates boxes with id="#box_"+i
    if(isEven(i))
        $("#box_"+i).css( "float","right" );
    else
        $("#box_"+i).css( "float","left" );
}
```

is even function

```
 function isEven(n) 
 {
     return (n % 2 == 0);
 }
```

I knew i was gonna need some jquery..

works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

if you wrap them in a div then it should work.

```
  <div id="bothleftnright"> 
     <div id="float-left" style="float:left;"></div>
     <div id="float-left2" style="float:left;"></div>
     <div id="float-right" style-"float:right;"></div>
  </div>
```

As Long as the outer div has a height that fits for all 3 divs then it should fix this.

Comment: "both" or "all three"?  You also have a typo in your code.  Please fix.

Answer (score -1):

Just put your two left boxes in a column which is floated to the left of the column on the right.

i.e.

```
<div class="column1" style="float:left;">
<div  class="box1">
    Here is box 1
</div>
<div  class="box3">
    Here is box 3
</div>
</div>
<div class="column2" style="float:right;">
    <div  class="box2">
        Here is box 2
    </div>
</div>
```